# MySQL Query between three tables (with also ORDER and LIMIT)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my table structure:

```sql
|----------------|
|    Feedback    |
|----------------|
|id              |
|workout_id      |
|comment (string)|
|----------------|



|----------------|
|    Workout     |
|----------------|
|id              |
|trainable_id    |
|----------------|



|----------------|
|  LiveTraining  |
|----------------|
|id              |
|title (string)  |
|----------------|
```

The *workout table* is a polymorph one, but that is beside the point.

What I need to do is this MySQL Query:

> **Display ALL the comments of the last 5 LiveTrainings, where the result will bring two columns: one with the title of LiveTraining and another with the answer.**

This should be the expected response:

```sql
|---------|---------|
|  Title  | Comment |
|---------|---------|
| Lorem 1 | Lorem 2 |
| Lorem 1 | Lorem 3 |
| Lorem 4 | Lorem 5 |
| Lorem 6 | Lorem 7 |
|---------|---------|
```

I was trying to do something like this (without success - empty response):

```sql
SELECT live_trainings.title, feedbacks.*
FROM workouts
INNER JOIN (select * FROM live_trainings order by id desc limit 5) live_trainings ON workouts.trainable_id = live_trainings.id
INNER JOIN feedbacks ON live_trainings.id = feedbacks.workout_id
```

Also tried some **UNION ALL** solutions, some **SELECT ( SELECT )**, among others.. all without success.

---

### VERY IMPORTANT: It must be a single Query solution, without functions or procedures at all :(

What would be the ideal query for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are joining  feedbacks to live_trainings instead of workouts. So try:

```
SELECT live_trainings.title, feedbacks.*
FROM workouts
INNER JOIN (select * FROM live_trainings order by id desc limit 5) live_trainings ON workouts.trainable_id = live_trainings.id
INNER JOIN feedbacks ON workouts.id = feedbacks.workout_id
```

If you are still having trouble, change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` and look for null fields. If the tables are big you might need to `LIMIT` the result

Comment: Perfect! Looks like, at least, I was on the way. Thank you very much!

In addition, I add this ```WHERE feedbacks.comment IS NOT NULL``` at the end of the query, to eliminate the feedbacks without any comment.

Comment: Glad it works for you. Changing `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` sometimes helps reveal the problem as the table failing the join will result in Nulls from the columns you are pulling from that table.